# Calculate the result of a formula loop VBA

Tags: vba, math, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the result of a formula using this code but for some reason i can't figure out why it is not printing in the loop...

```
Sub findx()
Dim A, B, fct As Variant
Dim k, i As Long

fct = InputBox("What is the function in terms of x?")
A = InputBox("Set lower boundary")
B = InputBox("Set upper boundary")
i = InputBox("How many times would you like to repeat this algorithm?")


Range("A6").Value = A
Range("B6").Value = B

For k = i To k = i + 6

Cells(k, 5).Value = "=" & Replace(LCase(fct), "x", Cells(k, 1).Value)
k = k + 1
Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove `k = k + 1`  - your For loop already takes care of this

Comment: `Cells(k, 5).Formula = "=" & Replace(LCase(fct), "x", Cells(k, 1).Value)`

Comment: Isn't it just `Cells(k, 5).Value = Replace(LCase(fct), "x", Cells(k, 1).Value)` or are you wanting a formula to appear in the cell?

Comment: Nothing changes unfortunately I already tried these combinations. Cells (k,5) remains empty.

Comment: Typo - `For k = i To i + 6`

Comment: Note: `A`, `B`, and `k` are all implicitly `Variant`. Also without input validation if the user enters `"abc"`, you get a *type mismatch* error on assignment of `i`.

Comment: oops! Thank you!